# TemplateDoesNotExist error in django with celery

Tags: python, django, selenium, web-scraping, celery

I am learning to use celery with django through this [tutorial](https://codeburst.io/making-a-web-scraping-application-with-python-celery-and-django-23162397c0b6). In this tutorial, the person is developing a webscraping tool with django and celery. I am trying to follow the tutorial but I am facing the following error message

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
home.html, scraping/products_list.html
```

this is how my files are arranged

```
.
├── celerybeat-schedule.db
├── celerydjangotutorial
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── celery.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   └── home.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── scraping
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   ├── 0002_auto_20200827_0735.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-38.pyc
    │       ├── 0002_auto_20200827_0735.cpython-38.pyc
    │       └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── tasks.py
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

where ***celerydjangotutorial*** is the django project and ***scraping*** is a django application. In the tutorial, the person places the templates into the project directory. he also creates a views file in the project directory. I followed him as he does in the tutorial. here is my code.

#### celerydjangotutorial/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import HomePageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

#### celerydjangotutorial/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from scraping.models import Products

class HomePageView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Products.objects.all()
```

#### scraping/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=2083, default="", unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="", blank=True, null=True)
```

#### scraping/tasks.py

```
import time
import json
from datetime import datetime

from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery import shared_task

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

@shared_task
def scrape():
    try:
        print('starting the scraping process')
        product_list = []
        url = f'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=chips&ref=nb_sb_noss_2'

        driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')

        driver.get(url)
        driver.implicitly_wait(15)

        links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("a-size-mini")
        for link in links:

            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, link.text)))

            product_meta = {
                'link': element.get_attribute('href'),
                'website': 'amazon'
            }

            product_list.append(product_meta)

        print('scraping process completed')
        return save_function(product_list)

    except Exception as e:
        print('scraping failed')
        print(e)

@shared_task(serializer='json')
def save_function(product_list):
    print('saving extracted data')
    new_count = 0

    for product in product_list:
        try:
            Products.objects.create(
                title = product['title'],
                link = product['link'],
                website = product['website']
            )
            new_count += 1

        except Exception as e:
            print('failed at latest_product is None')
            print(e)
            break

    return print('finished')
```

#### celerydjangotutorial/celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','celerydjangotutorial.settings')

app = Celery('celerydjangotutorial')
app.conf.timezone = 'UTC'
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

#### settings.py

```
...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'scraping.apps.ScrapingConfig'
]

...

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

...

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost:5672'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://localhost:5672'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I followed most of the tutorial. Except for tasks.py the rest of the code is similar to his code. Please help me.

Thanks in advance

## [EDIT-1] posting the entire error

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 81, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 63, in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "/Users/sashaanksekar/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 47, in select_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: home.html, scraping/products_list.html
```

Comment: Where is the `scraping/products_list.html` file? or where is the code that tries to access the `scraping/products_list.html` file?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu precisely. It does not exist. I am not sure why I am getting this error. That is why I posted the code here so you guys can look. And I have posted all the relevant code. Please let me know if I have to post something else

Comment: add your *complete error traceback*

Comment: @ArakkalAbu please take a look at the question. I have edited it to add the entire traceback

Comment: can you add the root view?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Not sure how to do that. Also I tried cloning the repo in the tutorial. That works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding app name under templates folder and move HTML files into it.
So it should be like
templates/celerydjangotutorial/
base.html
home.html

Comment: what about the settings.py code. should I change something there?

Answer (score 0):

Check the names of files, folders and path